# Can xml2js generate multiple text nodes under one parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml2js

I'm trying to generate XML containing structures similar to the following:

```xml
<p>
  Some text ...
  <bold>Bold text</bold>
  ... some more text ...
  <italic>Italic text</italic>
  ... and yet more text.
</p>
```

What input to `new xml2js.Builder().buildObject()` will obtain this structure?

Note that the children of the `p` element are a mix of element nodes and text nodes, and occur in a specific order.

**Background:** This is [JATS](https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/), not HTML. I'm modifying some existing code that produces XML for [Crossref](https://data.crossref.org/reports/help/schema_doc/4.4.2/index.html), and I have to add portions of JATS to the tree, a bit like [this](https://www.crossref.org/documentation/content-registration/descriptive-metadata/abstracts/). If xml2js simply can't produce these structures I will seek another tool, but that would require a substantial refactoring, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: Seems like you try to create a html site instead of xml. Why are you not using a template engine like handlebars?

Comment: @Marc This is not HTML, but rather, JATS. And I'm not working with set templates, so a handlebars-like approach doesn't seem right.

Comment: Your example seems to be well-formed XML("well-formed JATS")  ... so I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Q: Have you tried it yet?  What did you find?

Comment: @paulsm How can I try this? What is the structure of the javascript object I need to pass in to `new xml2js.Builder().buildObject()`?

Comment: *You're* asking *ME*?  I thought the whole point of your question - the entire reason you were considering xml2js - is that you were receiving some JSON (from "somewhere"), you wanted to convert it to JATS ("somehow") and you thought xml2js might do the job (sounds plausible).  Q: So where *ARE* you getting your input from?  Is it in JSON format (like I thought your question implied)?  And what led you to xml2js in the first place?  Are you considering other, different alternatives as well?

Comment: @paulsm I have tried to clarify the question. I'm modifying some code that uses xml2js to generate XML ([Crossref](https://data.crossref.org/reports/help/schema_doc/4.4.2/index.html) format), and I need to add portions of JATS to the tree. I have complete control of the input object, which is programmatically built, not ingested from JSON.
Essentially, my question is, what input to `new xml2js.Builder().buildObject()` will produce the desired output above?
I can switch to other tools if xml2js simply can't do it, but that will require a substantial refactoring of existing code.